# Add Buddypress profile and messages link to Wordpress menu

Tags: menus, buddypress

In the wordpress menu I would like to add a link to the buddypress user profile and messages. These links are dynamic based on the username like, http://buddypress.org/community/members/username/messages/, for example.

I know you can get the username with php but that is not allowed within wordpress menus (wp-admin/nav-menus.php) from what I can tell. I also need to add them at a specific place in the menu, not just at the end. What would be the simplest way to add these dynamic links to the wordpress menu?

Example:
Main Menu -> Human Resources -> Employee Resources -> Messages
Messages needs to link to the buddypress user's messages

Answer (score 5):

This will give you the user-specific profile URL:

```
<? echo bp_loggedin_user_domain(); ?>
```

If you'd the link to go to the user's Messages page, just add to the end like so:

```
<? echo bp_loggedin_user_domain().'messages/'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16223/add-buddypress-profile-menu-item) is the same as what you are asking; see if the answer to that question helps you.

If that doesn't help, you may want to see if the [BuddyPress Links](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress-links/) WordPress plug-in provides the additional functionality that you require.

If neither of those solutions prove helpful enough, please provide a link to your site and point out which menu you are trying to add BuddyPress links to and we can give you more specific information.

Comment: Thank you for the reply however the question you linked is for adding links to the buddypress menu where as I want to add buddypress links to the wordpress menu. Also BuddyPress Links seems to be more off a Digg style plugin where users can share links.

Unfortunately I can not provide a link to my site as it is an intranet and is locked down.

Answer (score 0):

The desire is to have "My Profile" "My Messages" as Wordpress Menu items. I'm not sure it can be done, because I've never seen a dynamic menu item before, and Salutation people kind of thought of everything...

HOWEVER, it just occurred to me that you could put a static link to a static page in the menu, but have those pages Dynamically Redirect based on `bp_get_user_id()` or whatever it is:

http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/wordpress-page-redirect

Sorry this isn't a full answer but I'm just being creative here.

So, make a menu item "My Profile" link = "example.com/redirects/my-profile" which then uses onwe of her methods to redirect them to example.com/members/%USERID% or something like that.